# VisualStudio 2010 Post-Build event to refresh chrome tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

i have a question about post-build events in visual studio 2010.
I have an MVC3 project and i want a post-build event that make a refresh on the current chrome tab. It's that possible?
What i have is a vb file with this code:

```
 set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.AppActivate "Google Chrome"
 WScript.Sleep 150
 WshShell.SendKeys "{f5}"
```

And in the post-build event command line of vs2010 i have:

```
cscript c:\test.vbs
```

But this doesn't refresh the page, only put on focus the chrome, but even so, if i hit f5 on my keyboard after the focus, the chrome doesn't refresh at all.
I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still looking for a solution 8 years later.

In my case I wanted to refresh my website after building my solution since my post-build event copies files to my website folder. I achieve it with this AutoHotkey script :

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

if WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Send {F5}
```

It maximizes my chrome window and send F5 to refresh the screen.

When I installed AutoHotkey, I checked the option to install the tool that compiles your script in an executable, which I named RefreshSite.exe. This was done by right-clicking my script and clicking on **Compile Script**

Finally, my post build event is :

```
xcopy "MySource" "MyDesination" /s /y
start "" "C:\Projets\AutoHotkey Scripts\RefreshSite.exe"
```

This solution isn't perfect, if your site is in another tab, the wrong tab will get refreshed. It can probably be improved but was good enough for me.